# Unable to locate package ros-noetic-turtlebot3

Tags: turtlebot, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I am trying to install the turtlebot3 binaries under ROS Noetic via

`sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-turtlebot3`.

However, I get the error:

`E: Unable to locate package ros-noetic-turtlebot3`

When checking http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_noetic_default.html?q=turtlebot I can see, that only `turtlebot3_msgs` is available for installation right now:
[image: image description]

Does this mean the other packages (such as `turtlebot3`, `turtlebot3_bringup`, `turtlebot3_description`, ...) have not yet been released for Noetic? Or are these packages temporarily not available?

Appreciate any help,
thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/364326/unable-to-locate-package-ros-noetic-turtlebot3/) by [toebgen](https://answers.ros.org/users/61046/toebgen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2020-10-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JackB](https://answers.ros.org/users/40162/jackb/) on 2020-10-28**:
You are sure the platform you are trying to download this on has internet access? Also can you install other ROS packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The status you see in that report show that it's been recently released and is available in the testing repository at the moment and will be expected in the main repository after the next sync.

More information on the testing repository is here: http://wiki.ros.org/TestingRepository If you'd like to try it from the testing repository, any feedback from there would be appreciated. But note that if you enable it you'll be at the front of the testing cycle so things may be slightly less stable.

Noetic syncs are tracked here: https://discourse.ros.org/c/release/noetic/66

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2020-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1